# Use gparted to format a flash drive

Tags: xubuntu, gparted

I have xubuntu on a flash drive and want to supress it and then burn ubuntu last version on it.I downloaded gparted and tried to use it to format my flash drive, but I can't find the right way to do so. In a tutorial I found, they counseled me to format it to "fat32", but I don't find it this in the options of gparted. When I choose to "create new partitions", I can only choose in the format aix, amiga, bsd, dvh, gpt, mac, msdos, pc98, sun or loop. Which one should I use to correctly format the flash drive and then be able to burn ubuntu?

Comment: @duncan That comment seems more like an answer to me ;)

Comment: @duncan If it answers the question, it answers the question, better a question answered than not :)

Comment: @ duncan Thanks for you comment, I definitely take that for an answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Those items you mentioned (aix, amiga, bsd, etc) are partition ***table*** types. The 2 most common for a linux installation are MSDOS and GPT.

Don't confuse them with partition types.

One way to format a partition is to right-click on the partition, choose format, and a lot of options will come up, including FAT32.